# Using Searchlogic with multiple models from one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

How exactly do I use Searchlogic with multiple models?  I have a dashboard that pulls data from 3 models and displays them in a grid (table) - I want to allow sorting and searching for all three of these, but Searchlogic seems to demand that I use "search" as the parameter name; doing something like:

```
@users_search = User.search(params[:user_search])
@reports_search = Report.search(params[:report_search])
```

in the Controller and:

```
<%= order @users_search, :by => :email_address, :as => "Email" %>
```

in the View does nothing when I try to sort the records.  Changing one of them to just `params[:search]` works, but isn't what I need for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to monkey_patch your Searchlogic

http://binarylogic.lighthouseapp.com/projects/16601/tickets/129-change-default-name-of-paramssearch